# tmpfs and disk partitionning (incoherent partition size between df and fdisk)

Tags: partition, disk-usage, fdisk

I will soon run out of space on my hard drive. Therefore I tried to change the
partitions and I discovered something that I don't understand.

`df -h` gives mes this output :

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda11      120G   11G  103G  10% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  8.7M  3.2G   1% /run
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda9        92G   36G   52G  41% /home
tmpfs           1.6G  4.0K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

I assumed that linux is running on partitions `sda9` and `sda11`. Note that the
total size of all the  `tmpfs` is roughly 21GB (possible to reduce ?). I
checked with `fdisk` if this was indeed the case :

```
Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0007ac02

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048   1953791   1951744   953M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2         1955838 488396799 486440962   232G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5         1955840   2148351    192512    94M 83 Linux
/dev/sda6         2150400  11913215   9762816   4.7G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7        11915264  31444991  19529728   9.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda8        31447040  33398783   1951744   953M 83 Linux
/dev/sda9        33400832 228710399 195309568  93.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda10      482619392 488396799   5777408   2.8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda11 *    228712448 482609151 253896704 121.1G 83 Linux
```

I realized then that besides `sda2` (the partition I would like to use to
increase my storage space) and `sda10` (which is the swap) I have 5 other
partitions that I was not aware of (`sda1, sda5, sda6, sda7, sda8`) and whose
total size is roughly 15GB.

By running a `df -h` on each of them I got:

```
office :: ~ » df -h /dev/sda1
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
```

The confusion comes from the fact that each of these partition has a size of
10M where before I had 15GB or 21GB in total.

My question :  what should I do if I want to create a partition in
`/home/username/new_partion/` with all the space available in `sda2` plus
eventually the `sda1, sda5, sda6, sda7` and `sda8` if those partition could be
deleted/reduced in size ?

Comment: Look carefully: you can run `df` on anything and it will tell you the stats for the filesystem it's on, in this case, `/dev/`. (See the "Mounted on" column.) So those 10M have nothing to do with the storage capacity of /dev/sda1.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz, yes but If I compare the size of `/dev/sda9/` with the two commands they almost match (92GB vs 93.1GB)

Answer (score 1):

`df` shows the free disk space on **mounted** partitions. If you give it a device name, it will try to find the corresponding mounted partition, and show you that; that's why `df /dev/sda9` works on your system. But since `/dev/sda1` isn't mounted, it finds the "closest" mounted filesystem, which is `/dev`, an 10MB RAM-based filesystem in your case.

To find out the available space on an unmounted partition, you need to use some other tool. For `ext2`/`ext3`/`ext4`, you can use `dumpe2fs`:

```
sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 | head -n 46
```

will show you a bunch of information about the overall filesystem (after line 46 it show details of groups, which aren't relevant here). The lines you're looking for in particular are `Block size` and `Free blocks`; they will allow you to determine the free space in the filesystem.

As to your actual question, you could delete the partitions in `sda5` to `sda8` if you don't need their contents, create a new `sda5` using all the space available, and mount that as `/home/username/new_partition`. `sda2` is a container partition for all the "extended" partitions, you can't use that. You could delete `sda1`, resize `sda2` and re-use the free space but it would be trickier...

Watch out for device renumbering if you do any of this though, if your `/etc/fstab` uses `/dev/sda9` and `/dev/sda11` rather than UUIDs for mounting partitions then you'll need to correct it.